# Android: how to set build.gradle file to run a plugin task automatically after sync

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

In our project we imported a plugin to check licenses documentary automatically. 
We need to execute that plugin task manually or set Android studio to do that check.

We want to do that task automatically after sync.
Is it possible to set build.gradle file to do that? And if the check failed, it would show build failed and print out the details like we execute that task manually.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task.dependencies)

```
task yourTaskName(...) {...}
project.afterEvaluate {
  preBuild.dependsOn yourTaskName
}
clean.dependsOn yourTaskName
clean.mustRunAfter yourTaskName
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This do execute yourTaskName after sync, but how can I call my plugin task?

Comment: I tried some thing like  `commandLine 'gradle', 'xxxx' `, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. When you add `apply plugin "your_plugin"`, I think its tasks will automatically be called after sync?. You can try to call manually in `command line`: `./gradlew :app:yourTaskName`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can execute that one task of that plugin to do the check manually, but we want it to do it automatically.